# Geofences not working on android, no transitions being triggered - Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-api, geofencing

I have created a service to run in the background at all times. The service will start geofencing, paired with a broadcast receiver to handle the transition events.

To test whether my service and receiver are working I added a counter and it works great. The counter works when the app is open, minimized or killed. But for some reason, the geofencing isn't receiving any transition events.

Any idea why? I know there were a lot of location updates introduced in android 12 but I don't see any warnings in this regard.

**The main activity, simple button turn service on or off:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
 lateinit var btn: Button
 lateinit var text: TextView


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    btn = findViewById(R.id.button)
    text = findViewById(R.id.text)
    checkText()

    btn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        if (GeofencingService.isServiceStarted){
            GeofencingService.isParticipatingOn = false
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, GeofencingService::class.java)
            stopService(intent)
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext ,"Remove GeoFences", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            Log.e("Main", "Geofences service killed")
            text.text = "Geofencing Stopped"
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext ,"Start Foreground", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            Log.e("Main", "Geofences service started")
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, GeofencingService::class.java)
            startService(intent)
            text.text = "Geofencing Started"
        }
    })


}
private fun checkText(){
    if (GeofencingService.isServiceStarted){
        text.text = "Geofencing Started"
    }
    else{
        text.text = "Geofencing Stopped"
    }
}

}
```

**This is my service:**

```
class GeofencingService: Service()  {
 private var geofencingClient: GeofencingClient? = null

companion object{
    var geofencelist = mutableListOf<Geofence>()
    var isServiceStarted = false
    var isParticipatingOn = false
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    Log.e("Main", "Geofences onCreate")
    isServiceStarted = true
    isParticipatingOn = true
    geofencelist.clear()
    geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this)
    startCustomForeground()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    Log.e("Main", "Geofences onDestroy")
    isServiceStarted = false
    removeGeoFences()
    if (isParticipatingOn){
        val intent = Intent(this, GeofencingService::class.java)
        intent.action = "RESTART_GEOFENCE_EVENT"
        startService(intent)
        //this.sendBroadcast(intent)
    }
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    //startForegroundService(intent)
    if (GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        geofencelist.add(
            Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId("KEY")
                .setCircularRegion(
                    lat, // lat
                    long, // long
                    3220f // meters
                )
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER or Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setNotificationResponsiveness(120000)
                .build())
        timer()
        addGeofences()

    } else {
        Log.e("Service", "Your Device doesn't support Google Play Services.")
    }

    return START_NOT_STICKY
}
override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
    return null
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun addGeofences(){
    geofencingClient?.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), geofencePendingIntent)?.run {
        addOnSuccessListener {
            // Geofences added
            Log.e("Main", "Geofences added")
            // ...
        }
        addOnFailureListener {
            // Failed to add geofences
            // ...
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun removeGeoFences(){
    geofencingClient?.removeGeofences(geofencePendingIntent)?.run {
        addOnSuccessListener {
            // Geofences removed
            Log.e("Main", "Geofences removed")
            // ...
        }
        addOnFailureListener {
            // Failed to remove geofences
            // ...
        }
    }
}


private fun getGeofencingRequest(): GeofencingRequest {
    return GeofencingRequest.Builder().apply {
        setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER or GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL or GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT)
        addGeofences(geofencelist)
    }.build()
}

private val geofencePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
    val intent = Intent(this, GeofencingBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
    intent.action = "START_GEOFENCE_EVENT"
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling
    // addGeofences() and removeGeofences().

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S){
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
    }else{
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }

}

private fun startCustomForeground() {
    val CHANNEL_ID = "GEOFENCING"
    val CHANNEL_NAME = "Geofencing Service"
    val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE)
    channel.lightColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE

    val manager = (getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager)
    manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

    val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder =
        NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
    val notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
        .setContentTitle(CHANNEL_NAME + "is running in background")
        .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE)
        .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
        .build()
    startForeground(1, notification)
}

private fun timer(){
    val timer = object: CountDownTimer(200000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            Log.e("Counter: ", millisUntilFinished.toString())
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, GeofencingBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
            intent.action = "TIMER"
            applicationContext.sendBroadcast(intent)
        }

        override fun onFinish() {}
    }
    timer.start()

}
```

}

**This is my broadcast reciver:**

```
class GeofencingBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

    if (intent?.action == "START_GEOFENCE_EVENT"){
        val geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent)
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            val errorMessage = GeofenceStatusCodes
                .getStatusCodeString(geofencingEvent.errorCode)
            Log.e("Broadcaster", errorMessage)
            return
        }
        // Get the transition type.
        Log.e("Potato", " Geofencing service broadcast started")
        val geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.geofenceTransition
        val triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.triggeringLocation

        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
        when (geofenceTransition) {
            (Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER )-> {

                Toast.makeText(context,"ENTER - "+ triggeringGeofences.longitude.toString() +" - "+ triggeringGeofences.latitude.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                Log.i("Potato", "ENTER - Lat: ${triggeringGeofences.latitude} - Long: ${triggeringGeofences.longitude}")

            }
            (Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) -> {

                Toast.makeText(context,"EXIT - "+ triggeringGeofences.longitude.toString() +" - "+ triggeringGeofences.latitude.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                Log.i("Potato", "EXIT - Lat: ${triggeringGeofences.latitude} - Long: ${triggeringGeofences.longitude}")
            }
            else -> {
                Log.e("Potato", " ERROR")
            }
        }
    }

    else if(intent?.action == "RESTART_GEOFENCE_EVENT" ) {
        if (!GeofencingService.isServiceStarted){
            Log.e("Potato", " Geofencing service restarted")
            val intentService = Intent(context, GeofencingService::class.java)
            context?.let { ContextCompat.startForegroundService(it,intentService) }
        }
    }
    else if(intent?.action == "TIMER" ) {
        Log.e("Potato", " TIMER TICKING ++")
    }

}
}
```

**Manifest changes:**

```
<receiver android:name=".GeofencingBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="GeofencingBroadcastReceiver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".GeofencingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location">
    </service>
```

Comment: Have you found any useful solutions?

Comment: My solution was to create my own custom Geofencing system from scratch as I wasn't able to figure out why it won't function on Samsung devices. As mentioned, the geofencing library provided by Google was not Functional on Samsung devices for some reason.